# With a Java ExecutorService, how do I complete actively executing tasks but halt the processing of waiting tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using an ExecutorService (a ThreadPoolExecutor) to run (and queue) a lot of tasks. I am attempting to write some shut down code that is as graceful as possible.

ExecutorService has two ways of shutting down:

1. I can call `ExecutorService.shutdown()` and then `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(...)`.
2. I can call `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()`.

According to the JavaDoc, the `shutdown` command:

```
Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted
tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
```

And the `shutdownNow` command:

```
Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the
processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were
awaiting execution.
```

I want something in between these two options.

I want to call a command that:
  a. Completes the currently active task or tasks (like `shutdown`).
  b. Halts the processing of waiting tasks (like `shutdownNow`).

For example: suppose I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with 3 threads. It currently has 50 tasks in the queue with the first 3 actively running. I want to allow those 3 active tasks to complete but I do not want the remaining 47 tasks to start.

I believe I can shutdown the ExecutorService this way by keeping a list of `Future` objects around and then calling `cancel` on all of them. But since tasks are being submitted to this ExecutorService from multiple threads, there would not be a clean way to do this.

I'm really hoping I'm missing something obvious or that there's a way to do it cleanly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: +1 it's difficult to understand why such a feature is not included in ExecutorService.  It sometimes seems that language/library developers have never actually written any multiThreaded apps.  Draining the queue, settting some 'Interrupted' flag, (or pushing suicide requests), and waiting for the current runnables to complete seems like a reasonable and common requirement.

Comment: Seems like a very reasonable request.  Since I subscribe to the concurrency-interest email list I'll ask there.

Comment: The suggestions I got were very similar to the suggestions by irreputable and Kublai Khan.  Either check isShutdown() or call shutdown() and clear (or drain) the queue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently. There may be a more elegant approach, but my solution is to first call `shutdown()`, then pull out the `BlockingQueue` being used by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and call `clear()` on it (or else drain it to another `Collection` for storage). Finally, calling  `awaitTermination()` allows the thread pool to finish what's currently on its plate.

For example:

```
public static void shutdownPool(boolean awaitTermination) throws InterruptedException {

    //call shutdown to prevent new tasks from being submitted
    executor.shutdown();

    //get a reference to the Queue
    final BlockingQueue<Runnable> blockingQueue = executor.getQueue();

    //clear the Queue
    blockingQueue.clear();
    //or else copy its contents here with a while loop and remove()

    //wait for active tasks to be completed
    if (awaitTermination) {
        executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

This method would be implemented in the directing class wrapping the `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the reference `executor`.

It's important to note the following from the [`ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getQueue%28%29) javadoc:

> Access to the task queue is intended primarily for debugging and
>   monitoring. This queue may be in active use. Retrieving the task queue
>   does not prevent queued tasks from executing.

This highlights the fact that additional tasks may be polled from the `BlockingQueue` while you drain it. However, all `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe according to [that interface's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), so this shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: I will give this a try. BlockingQueue uses a `ReentrantLock` for just about every action, so I'm not sure if the synchronized is necessary.

Comment: @JeffGoldberg Ah, good point. I'll have to revisit whether that's needed when I get a chance. This is why I love SO :)

Comment: Not sure what I was talking about with BlockingQueue using a lock. BlockingQueue is an interface so it uses nothing. I think I was looking at PriorityBlockingQueue.

Comment: Ok, so, well, if you use the Executors class to get a newFixedThreadPool it uses a LinkedBlockingQueue, which also has both put and take locks. Anyway, I'll implement this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: One other note: in your sample code, you should call `executor.shutdown();` _before_ clearing the queue. Otherwise there's the risk that another thread could add a task the to ExecutorService after you've cleared it but before you've shut it down. Since shutdown simply prevents new tasks from being added, it's safe to call that first.

Comment: @JeffGoldberg - You're absolutely right. My solution was coded with the condition that no tasks would come in after the shutdown call, so I forgot this possibility. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @JeffGoldberg - So about the synchronized block, it seems safer to leave it, since it looks like `ThreadPoolExecutor` can take a variety of `BlockingQueue` implementations.

Comment: Preliminary tests show this approach working well, but since mimicking complex multithreading logic is tricky I'm not sure if I've accurately represented all use cases in the test logic. I'll accept this as the answer next week once I've had more time to verify it.

Comment: @JeffGoldberg I know it's been a year and a half, but I happened on this answer again and realized the synchronized block was in fact unnecessary since all `BlockingQueue`s are documented to be thread-safe. Not only that, I was using `synchronized` incorrectly and it wouldn't have done anything anyway. All the best.

Comment: instead of executor.getQueue().clear() , you are getting a reference to a "final" variable and then clearing it. Do you have a specific reason for getting a reference? and the reference being final?

Comment: @kommradHomer No, that's just a matter of style. `executor.getQueue().clear()` would be equivalent and that's probably what I have in the actual code.

Comment: @PaulBellora alright. Just wanted to see if theres an exotic reason behind :)

Answer (score 5):

The `shutdownNow()` is exactly what you need. You've missed the 1st word *Attempts* and the entire 2nd paragraph of its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29):

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

So, only tasks which are checking [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) on a regular basis (e.g. in a `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())` loop or something), will be terminated. But if you aren't checking on that in your task, it will still keep running.

Comment: My concern about this approach is there are times when I **do** actually want to interrupt active tasks. They currently do check interrupted status and handle InterruptedExceptions properly, because in emergencies (or at the end of a daily cycle) I need to shut everything down immediately.

Comment: Add an extra check next to the interrupted status whether there's means of an emergency state.

Comment: In addition to `Thread.isInterrupetd()`, there are other interruption points, including `Thread.sleep()`, `Thread.join()`, and `Object.wait()`.

Comment: @John: Yes, the ones throwing `InterruptedException`. It's however very rare to use any of them in an executor task.

Comment: @BalusC: I think this is a valid and good answer, but I disagree that it's very rare to find `InterruptedException` cases in an executor task. My tasks definitely deal with them--there's a lot of threads which are  pausing as they wait for third party activities so as to free up resources for other threads. In fact, I don't understand why you wouldn't _always_ expect that behavior. The `InterruptedException` seems especially designed for the situation where you have multiple threads being run at one time by an executor.

Comment: Well, perhaps because I've myself never used and seen them that way in real world applications. But that can perhaps be because I mainly develop web applications only.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap each submitted task with a little extra logic

```
wrapper = new Runnable()
    public void run()
        if(executorService.isShutdown())
            throw new Error("shutdown");
        task.run();

executorService.submit(wrapper);
```

the overhead of extra checking is negligible. After executor is shutdown, the wrappers will still be executed, but the original tasks won't.

Comment: This is a very good idea. To avoid having to wrap every single Runnable or Callable in your code, you could instead extend the `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or the ExecutorService of your choice), override the overloaded `newTaskFor` methods, and wrap all incoming Callable/Runnable tasks with your special "AbortOnShutdownCallable/Runnable".

If Kublai Khan's "clear the blocking queue" approach ends up not working, I'll try this. But either way +1.