# "escape" element in LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java

I am circling through `LinkedBlockingQueue` millions of Strings.
The reading thread should end its execution when there are no more items in source.

I thought about putting a dummy value like `"SHUTDOWN"` in `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

The reader does this:

```
while ((data = (String)MyLinkedBlockingQueue.take()).equals("SHUTDOWN") == false) {
    //read and live 
}
```

Is it efficient to execute equals on every string? If not what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  This is the standard idiom for finishing processing of a BlockingQueue, it's called the "poison pill".  i usually implement it using a special private static final instance so you can do object equality and don't risk overlapping with a real value.  e.g.:

```
private static final String SHUTDOWN = new String("SHUTDOWN"); // use new String() so you don't get an interned value

public void readQueue() {
  while ((data = (String)MyLinkedBlockingQueue.take()) != SHUTDOWN) {
      //read and live 
  }
}

public void shutdownQueue() {
  MyLinkedBlockingQueue.put(SHUTDOWN);
}
```

Comment: Note that this has the side effect that the only way to shut down the queue is to call `shutdownQueue()`.  Conversely, if you used the string literal (and/or called `intern()`) then anybody could shut down the queue by calling `put("SHUTDOWN")`.  Which one you want would depend on the semantics you intend.

Comment: @DanielPryden - well, anybody can shutdown the queue by calling `shutdownQueue()` as well.  and this way keeps the queue management logic well encapsulated.

Comment: @jtahlborn, can you please explain why I can't use interned string?

Comment: @jullin: That's what my comment was about.  You *could* use an interned string, but that would allow anybody to insert the literal string `"SHUTDOWN"` instead of calling `shutdownQueue()`.  Keeping the String instance private enforces that only the the class's special `SHUTDOWN` value can be used to shut down the queue, instead of any String that happens to contain the characters "SHUTDOWN".  As I said in my comment, which one you want depends on the semantics you intend.  But I think jtahlborn makes a good point that keeping the logic encapsulated is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of using `poll()` and ending the loop when it returns null.

Comment: not good, because queue can be idle for some time but source have more data to put.

Comment: Ok. Then if you are concerned about efficiency of equals() why not make SHUTDOWN a constant and use '==' for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented so that you don't have to check for the "poison pill" every time. Consider making use of a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) that works on your `LinkedBlockingQueue`. When you want to shut down processing, call the [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown%28%29) method on the executor object. From the documentation of that method:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.

See this post if you're interested in shutting down processing immediately while tasks are still pending in the queue: [With a Java ExecutorService, how do I complete actively executing tasks but halt the processing of waiting tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8158500/697449)